# Are there any other references to Willow?

Tags: books, george-lucas, willow

I read the first two books of the *"Shadow War"* Trilogy when they first came out in 1995 and 1996.

As a kid I loved the movie Willow and felt that the books kind of ruined the movie for me since they are sequels to the movie. It was the first time I knew of George Lucas re-editing or in his mind "fixing" the original and so I've never been surprised by the Star Wars edits that followed.

My question is; Other than the first part of the first book and the name Elora Danan, **are there any other instances in the trilogy that actually reference the movie or characters in *Willow***?

Comment: *::makes a note to self **"Never read any 'Shadow War' books"**::* I mean, *Willow* was bloody brilliant. Why mess with it?

Comment: Well that's kind of why I asked. If there is no more mention I can pull the mental trick that I did with the Matrix Sequels and just think of them as non-cannon fanfic. It's mostly Chris Clairmont's writings with a few ideas thrown in by Lucas.

Comment: @dmckee Are you sure you don't want to read the Nelwyn sex scene with Willow and his wife?  I about clawed out my eyes.

Comment: @Legion600 My ... uhm ... *friend* tells me there's places to get you fix on the internet. Or so I hear. From my *friend*. *// I really hope you're kidding. Obviously there needs to be a next generation of Nelwyn, but I don't want to hear the gory details.*

Comment: @dmckee I'm sadly, unfortunately, seriously not kidding.

Comment: @dmckee It's too damn late for me, wish i'd never read em, they were so damn dark and gloomy I never bothered finishing the series. The first 2 books were so depressing that when the 3rd came out I just went straignt to the end to find out what happened and even the ending was depressing.

Comment: @Dai Yeah I had the same reaction except by the time the third one came out I didn't even care how it ended I knew it could only get worse. This is the series that I really try to forget existed, even more than the Matrix sequels. Although the woman that was possessed by Chaos in the series was an interesting one.

Comment: @dmckee - I've glanced at the books and I can sincerely confirm that they're a pile of cack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second book (**[Shadow Dawn](http://willowufgood.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Dawn)**) makes almost zero reference to any of the main characters in the film Willow, aside from a single paragraph in the first chapter and a couple of later mentions of Bavmorda being a [psycho hose beast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQhdJvtIl2g);

> Bards told the story better, but they were supposed to, that was their
>   profession. Each time she heard it, there was some new twist, an even
>   more fantastical adventure to add spice to the retelling. Much more
>   romance, for example, between Madmartigan and Sorsha, the wayward
>   warrior and the princess who turned from evil to good for love. And
>   Elora's guardian, her godfather, the Nelwyn sorcerer Willow Ufgood,
>   assumed a majesty of bearing, a force of command that would have done
>   a Daikini warlord proud.

I've just finished flicking through the Third (and final) book in the series; [Shadow Star](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553572881). About halfway through the book, Elora reminisces about her relationship with Willow, Madmartigan and Sorsha;

> She took no action against Madmartigan and Sorsha; the elves saved her
>   the trouble. So it went, year after year, generation upon generation.
>   Because she lost faith in her generals, she trained herself in all the
>   warriors' arts. When she grew convinced that Willow was rousing the
>   local wizards to rebellion, she mastered their arts as well. And
>   remembering the breadth of Bavmorda's power, it was the most logical
>   progression from the craft of white magic to that of black.

Later in the book, there's a substantial subplot involving a time travel device in which Elora sees (and fights) Bavmorda and Kael.

> The Resonator initiated another pulse and with it another timeslip, to
>   the seminal moment of Elora's infancy, when Kael had stolen her away
>   from Thorn and his companions and galloped her to Nockmaar to be
>   sacrificed. True, an army had followed hot on his heels, composed of
>   the survivors of those great castles who'd already fallen to
>   Bavmorda's sorcery, the latest being gallant Galadoorn, but Kael gave
>   it little thought. Nockmaar had never fallen that he knew of, and
>   would never fall while he held command.
>   Of course, it did, the very next morning, as Kael's men were hoodwinked into chasing Thorn and Fin Raziel across the plain, only to
>   have the army they believed transformed entirely into pigs rise up out
>   of hidey-holes dug in the ground, fully restored and spoiling for
>   vengeance.
>
> It was an epic battle, between Sorsha and her mother (Sorsha lost), between Fin Raziel and the woman who'd been her best friend (Fin lost), and finally between the Nelwyn who wanted to be a wizard
>   and the greatest demon sorceress of her age. With a little bit of
>   luck, some dexterous sleight of hand, and a fatal moment of clumsy
>   footwork from the opposition, Thorn won the day and saved Elora's
>   life. The Ritual intended for her consumed Bavmorda instead, utterly
>   and completely.

Comment: @KevinHowell - It certainly puts a new spin on Willow. After reading these, I was positively cheering for Kael to kill Elora.